# better way of extracting values from string

Tags: python

```
str = 'This is first line \n 2 line start from her\ Service Name: test \n some 4 line \n User Name: amit \n some something \n Last Name: amit amit \n
```

Basically What I am interested is getting the service name and user name.
Should I user regular expression for doing this.
I want to create a dict like

```
dict['service_name'] = 'test'
dict['user_name'] = 'amit'
dict['last_name'] = 'amit amit'
```

So what the best way of searching and getting the values.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given:

```
str = 'This is first line \n 2 line start from her\nService Name: test \n some 4 line \nUser Name: amit \n some something \nLast Name: amit amit \n'
```

The following code:

```
dict([line.split(':') for line in str.split('\n') if ':' in line])
```

produces:

```
{'Last Name': ' amit amit ', 'Service Name': ' test ', 'User Name': ' amit '}
```

You may want to change `split(':')` to `split(':', 1)` to avoid issues with colons on the right-hand sides. Additionally, you may want to sprinkle a few calls to `strip` if whitespaces are an issue.

Comment: Add some strip()s and you are there IMO.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very elegnat, but you can explode() the string into an array using 'Service Name:' as the separator.

Comment: My mistake, thinking PHP function names not Python, you need split not explode.